# jQuery: on vs live

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I am curious why when I replace `.live()` with `.on()` my events don't work after inserting AJAX's response via `html()` method. Assume I have html structure:

```
<div class="a">
   <a href="" class="alert-link">alert</a>
   <a href="" class="ajax-update">update</a>
</div>
```

and jQuery code something like:

```
$('.alert-link').on("click", function(){
 alert('abc');
 return false;
});
```

and ajax-update will trigger request, which response will be:

alert
update

and I will insert it into `parent()`. Then pressing again `alert-link` will result in redirecting to `/` but if I change `.on()` to `.live()` then again alert will be shown. What am I missing here? I have read that `.on()` is replacement both for `.delegate()` and `.live()`.

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking here bwhat is alert update,? Can up you make a jsfiddle to show us an example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When using jQuery on(), why use (document) vs. the element itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418991/when-using-jquery-on-why-use-document-vs-the-element-itself)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.on` combines and replaces **`.bind`**, `.live`, and `.delegate`.  The syntax `$('selector').on('event', callback)` is the moral equivalent of `bind`, not `live`.

Add a filtering selector to your call to `on`:

```
$('container').on('click', 'child-filter', callback);
```

In this case,

```
$('.a').on("click", ".alert-link", function(){
    alert('abc');
    return false;
});
```

This was changed because it is more efficient to attach a delegate handler to a more localized container element than the old `.live` style of attaching the handler to the root of the DOM.

In other words, even though `alert-link` elements will only appear inside of a small `a` `div`, with `.live`, jQuery listens to *every single click event on the page* and compares it to the delegated selector.  By being more targeted, jQuery only has to process clicks on elements within `a`.

Comment: I am accepting this answer instead of the one provided by icktoofay because of additional explanation why my syntax did not work. 3 minutes to go.

Answer (score 7):

Your particular conversion to `.on()` didn't work properly because you were using the static form of `.on()` instead of the dynamic form of `.on()`.  Instead of the static form:

```
$('.alert-link').on("click", function(){
```

you need to use the dynamic form like this:

```
$(someStaticParentObject).on("click", '.alert-link', function(){
```

This will bind the event handler to `someStaticParentObject` and then use delegated event handling for any child events that originate on an item that matches the selector `'.alert-link'`.  Your version was immediately binding to whatever `'.alert-link'` items existed at the time you installed the event handler (static binding) and was not using delegated event handling to handle events from objects that aren't yet created.

See these previous answers for a good explanation of `.live()` vs. `.on()` and why `.live()` can lead to performance issues in some cases:

[Does jQuery.on() work for elements that are added after the event handler is created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814298/does-jquery-on-work-for-elements-that-are-added-after-the-event-handler-is-cre/9814409#9814409)

[How does jQuery's new on() method compare to the live() method in performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541825/how-does-jquerys-new-on-method-compare-to-the-live-method-in-performance/8541838#8541838)

[What's the difference between jQuery.bind() and jQuery.on()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113783/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-bind-and-jquery-on/9113835#9113835)

[jQuery .live() vs .on() method for adding a click event after loading dynamic html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht/8752376#8752376)

[Why not take Javascript event delegation to the extreme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711118/why-not-take-javascript-event-delegation-to-the-extreme/9711252#9711252)

In a nutshell:

```
$(".item").live('click', fn);
```

is functionality equivalent to:

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', fn);
```

The two main drawbacks of `.live()` are:

1. It evaluates the selector `".item"` immediately which is purely wasted cycles because the result isn't used at all.
2. `.live()` is hardwired to the document object.  It uses delegated event handling to be able to handle objects that come and go, but all `.live()` event handlers are assigned to the document object.  If you have a lot of them, it can be a big performance bottleneck because every event that bubbles up to the document has to be evaluated against the selectors of all `.live()` event handlers.  `.on()` on the other hand can be bound not only to the document object, but also to an ancestor that is much closer to the actual origin of the events and when there are lots of delegated event handlers, it can be a LOT more efficient to find the events closer so that only the events that are close to the object are processed through the `.on()` selectors, thus improving performance.  For example, the above handlers could be done like this:

   ```
   $("#container").on('click', '.item', fn);
   ```

where `#container` is a parent of the dynamic `.item` objects.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed a replacement for `.delegate` and `.live`, but you have to pass in some additional parameters:

```
var container = $('.a').on('click', '.alert-link', function() {
    alert('abc');
    return false;
}).on('click', '.ajax-update', function() {
    // something that uses AJAX to update .a, like:
    container.load('some-url');
    return false;
});
```

For more information, [see the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: According to the jQuery [docs for .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), the selector and data parameters are optional.

Comment: @Surreal: Correct, but if `selector` is not provided, it behaves like `bind` rather than `delegate`.

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't realize that changed behavior like that.  Thanks.