# jquery on to replace live?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery: on vs live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864476/jquery-on-vs-live)

I have code that works just fine using `$('thing').live("mousemove", function(e) {` and `$('thing').live({mouseenter:function(e) {`. I notice jquery said `live` is depreciated and to use `on` so i did. However it doesn't seem to work the way i expect it to. I had mousemove events but since objects were loaded dynamically the events werent triggering which is why i use live. Now live works perfectly but when i use `on` as jquery suggested it seems to act like .mousemove and such. It works on objects that exist when the code is executed and not on dynamically added events (the whole reason i use live).

Is there a way to tell on to act like live and add events on new object? or do i use live?

Comment: Show what you had working with `live()` and then we can try and help you out. Or, at the *very* least, show the full working code you had with `live()` (and HTML too). Plus: [live demos are good too](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **delegate** your event if you want it to work for Dynamically added elements

```
$(anyStaticParent).on("mousemove", "thing", function() {

     // You code Here
});
```

**anyStaticParent** can be any parent container of `thing` ..
To be more general you can always set that to `body`

Also I see that `'thing'` is not a specific element ..

use `'.thing'`  - if Class

`'#thing'`  - if ID

Answer (score 2):

You just have to call `.on` in the correct way: `$(document).on(event, selector, handler)`:

```
// Use an element that exist, like document or "body".
$(document).on("mousemove", "thing", function() {
  // Do something here...
});
```

Check the three last examples in the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement `on` a tiny bit differently so it behaves like `live`, binding it to  the document with the selector as an argument:

```
$(document).on("mousemove", 'thing', function(e) { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to delegate with `.on` is to pass in a selector for dynamically added elements.

```
$('thing').on('mousemove', 'dynamically added thing', function(e) {
    //handler
});
```

For a less abstract example:

```
$("ul#menu").on("click", "li", function(event){
    //handler
});
```

Per the API, http://api.jquery.com/on/:

```
.on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )

.on( events-map [, selector] [, data] )
```

If `selector` is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as direct or directly-bound. The handler is called every time an event occurs on the selected elements, whether it occurs directly on the element or bubbles from a descendant (inner) element.

When a `selector` is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.