# jquery .addClass to set up another function using new class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, canvas

I'm working on a drawing app and running into some trouble with the use of .addClass.
What I'm trying to do is send a new class to a menu item that I can then use to run a function which clears my canvas. I can make the list item invoke the function on its own when the class is preset to 'new_file', but I would like to have it inactive until some drawing is done on the canvas. My idea was to use .addClass when a mousedown is detected on the canvas, but it's not working out as planned. Other ideas for how to accomplish this are encouraged as well. Here's some code:

This code from my canvas.js file clears the canvas when the list item with class 'new_file' is clicked.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.new_file').mousedown(function(){
          clearCanvas(); 
       });

       function clearCanvas(){
          context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width(), canvas.height());
       }
    });
```

This is what I tried for adding the class; it's in my 'head' for now:

```
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#myCanvas").click(function() {  //tried .mousedown; did nothing
               $("#clear").addClass("new_file");
           });
       });
    </script>
```

This is the list item I'm trying to manipulate:

```
    <li id="clear">Clear</li>
```

And my canvas:

```
    <canvas class="canvaso" id="myCanvas" height="239" width="414"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvas.js"></script>
```

I tried testing various edits while observing firebug but it seems like "new_file" isn't being added to the list item. Also tried changing #myCanvas and testing other IDs on the page but still couldn't get new_file added. Stumped.

Comment: You did a great job setting the stage, but I'm having trouble understanding exactly what the question is

Comment: In short, I was trying to add a class to a list item after a click event on my canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/). That way, when you add classes to an element, they are automatically binded to your function.

```
$('.new_file').live('mousedown', function(){
    clearCanvas(); 
});
```

If you are using jQuery 1.7+, use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `live` (as it is now deprecated).

Comment: Scroll a bit more: _As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()._ Basically `live` has no use anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works with .live but not .on. Are further edits required with the use of .on? I'm using 1.8.1

Comment: Well, yeah technically it can still be used, but even if `on` is not available `delegate` probably is unless jQ version is really old.

Comment: Point given for `delegate`. @metamlkshk: See the link at the end of the post.

Comment: @metamlkshk - you have to use the dynamic form of `.on()` (not the static form) as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985090/jquery-on-does-not-work-but-live-does/9985137#9985137

Comment: @jfriend et al. Thanks. Got it working with $(document).on('mousedown','.new_file', function(){etc});
Live seemed so much easier :)

Comment: @metamlkshk - `.live()` is simpler, but is less flexible and can have performance issues, particularly if used a lot.   There are good reasons not to use it any more and to learn how to use `.on()` efficiently.