# .on VS .live with uncreated content

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery .on does not work but .live does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985090/jquery-on-does-not-work-but-live-does)

I just can't find a clear answer.

I used to use the `$('.someclass).live('click', function ... )` for items created **on the fly with JS**, which of course does not work when updating jQuery 1.9.0 (thanks guys). I have been looking around and could not find a good answer. So, here's the question again :

What is the equivalent to .live **for items created on the fly** without having to reassign a click listener everytime i create a new item ? It is still working perfectly with older jQuery versions !!

Delegate, on and live are a no go. What is going on ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".someparent").on("click", ".someclass", function() {
    // ...
});
```

Where *.someparent* is the selector to the *.someclass* parent element.